# check template argument

Tags: c++, function, templates

I have a template class (A). How can I check if class T is derived from an abstract class IClass?

```
template <class T>
class A 
{
       //T have to be derived from abstract class IClass
} ;
```

thanks

Answer (score 4):

Using static asserts and `is_base_of` from Boost, TR1 or C++11:

```
template <class T>
class A {
public:
    BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(( boost::is_base_of<IClass, T>::value )); 
};
```

Comment: I knew there had to be a more packaged-up way of doing it.  Use this.

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do is referred to as a template concept check.  These were going to be a feature in C++11 but the standards committee cut it.

You can still do it though, it's just not as clean as it might otherwise be.  Bjarne Stroustrup explains how to do this on his FAQ: http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html#constraints

Specifically he gives this example:

```
template<class T, class B> struct Derived_from {
    static void constraints(T* p) { B* pb = p; }
    Derived_from() { void(*p)(T*) = constraints; }
};
```

Then you just declare a dummy parent inside your class so that it'll trip a compiler error:

```
template <class T> class A : Derived_from<T,IClass> { ... }
```

Stroustrup mentioned that this actually tests for conversion, not for inheritance.  There might be a way to test specifically for inheritance only, if that's what you need.